# Read each line of a text file, remove all characters before a specific string, then save as new file in Python

Tags: python-3.x

I've several documents of text message transcripts that need to have their usernames and timestamps removed.

For example:

```
06/01/2021, 13:43 - Blue Banana: Blah blah 
06/01/2021, 13:43 - Red Apple: Blah blah blah
06/01/2021, 13:43 - Blue Banana: Blah blah blah blah
```

to

```
Blah blah 
Blah blah blah
Blah blah blah blah
```

What I've got so far opens the command prompt for a second, and then closes it. 'Test Docu 2' does not change at all.

```
oldfile = "C:\\Users\\User\\Downloads\\Test Docu.txt"
newfile = "C:\\Users\\User\\Downloads\\Test Docu 2.txt"
newline = ""

with open(oldfile, 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        if "Blue Banana: " in line:
            newline = line[line.find("Blue Banana: "):]
            newfile.write(newline)
        elif "Red Apple: " in line:
            newline = line[line.find("Red Apple: "):]
            newfile.write(newline)
```

Comment: `newfile` is a string, so `newfile.write(...)` won't work. Try `open(newfile, 'w')`?

Comment: To fix the command prompt issue, don't "double click" your python script, use an actual IDE where you can run the code and see the error that write() is not a str function

Answer (score 1):

You need to open() the new file and write to that

You also should use a generic solution for any "username"

```
with open(oldfile) as f, open(newfile, 'w') as out:
    for line in f:
        time, txt = line.split('-', 1) 
        out.write(txt.split(':',1)[1].strip() + '\n')
```